# get previous and next elements within and ordered collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

Within a collection of components, one member is the active member.

```
@components = Component.order(id: :asc, sequence_order: :asc)
@component_ids = @components.pluck('id')
@present_component = Component.where('id = ?', params[:component_id]).first
```

To take advantage of turbolinks, the goal is to identify the previous and next items within this ordered collection.  How can the previous component be extracted?

```
 index = @components.find_index(@present_component.id)
 @previous = @components[index-1]
```

fails; I'd like to understand why.

Comment: What if the object were the first or last of the array, in which case there would be no previous or following element? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: by invoking `@previous = @components[index-1]` we get the last element, whether it is the previous or the last element [-1] of the ruby array, while `@next = @components[index+1] || @components[0]` will get the initial member of the array in case it is the last, thus closing the loop.

Comment: Yes, `@previous` is the previous or last element, but one needs to know which, since you are returning both the "previous" and "next" elements. Moreover, you haven't said what you want when `arr.size = 1`. My point is not how an answer can account for these special cases, but that the question needs to address them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@components` object is a list of Components, not Component ids, so you have to search like this:

```
 index = @components.find_index(@present_component)
```

or maybe you wanted to do this:

```
 index = @components_ids.find_index(@present_component.id)
```

Comment: yes, with the former, then `@prev = @components[index-1]` and `@next = @components[index+1] || @components[0]` run

Answer (score 0):

```
def neighbors(arr, item)
  idx = arr.index(item)
  return nil if idx.nil?
  return [nil, arr[idx+1]] if idx.zero?
  arr.values_at(idx-1, idx+1)
end
```

```
neighbors(["cat", "dog", "pig"], "dog")  #=> ["cat", "pig"] 
neighbors(["cat", "dog", "pig"], "owl")  #=> nil
neighbors(["cat", "dog", "pig"], "cat")  #=> [nil, "dog"] 
neighbors(["cat", "dog", "pig"], "pig")  #=> ["dog", nil] 
neighbors(["cat"], "cat")                #=> [nil, nil] 
neighbors([], "cat")                     #=> nil
```

Notice that:

- if `idx = nil`, `nil` is returned;
- else if `arr.size = 1`, `[,nil, nil]` is returned;
- else if `idx = 0`, `[,nil, arr[1]]` is returned;
- else if `idx = arr.size-1`, `[,arr[-1], nil]` is returned;
- else `[,arr[idx-1], arr[Iidx+1]` is returned.